# Pygame and sleep? Flashing an image on the screen and going back to the initial image

Tags: python, pygame, sleep

I've been racking my brain and trying to find how to:

1. Start a program displaying image 1  on a Pygame drawing surface
2. Flash image 2 for a short amount of time, like 2 seconds
3. Reset the program to the initial state (step 1)

For some reason, I'm getting an error message:

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'sleep'

I found a post (https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1129861) where the person having this error message had a file called time.py. That doesn't seem to be the problem here.

It seems that sleep should work inside Pygame ([animation in pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15868992/animation-in-pygame)).

What I'm trying to achieve here is not necessarily to stop the whole program, but just to display a different image while the program is running.

Here is my code. I am fully aware that it is far from elegant and I'm working on that also:

===

```
# This is my first game demonstration in python

import pygame, sys, random, time
from pygame import *
pygame.init()

# variables globales

global width, height
width, height = 500, 400
pygame.display.set_caption("Test Program")

global player, px, py
player = pygame.image.load("image 1.png") # load the player image
player = pygame.transform.scale(player, (125,125))
px,py = (width - 125)/2, (height - 125)/2 # pour centrer l'image

global DISPLAYSURF
DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 400), 0, 32)

def game():

    global player, px, py

    # set up the colors
    BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
    WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
    RED = (255, 0, 0)
    GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
    BLUE = (0, 0, 255)

    # draw on the surface object
    DISPLAYSURF.fill(BLACK)

    # speed of game and other variables initiated
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    gamespeed = 100
    movex = movey = 0

    score = 0

    # this is the score text loading
    gamefont = pygame.font.Font(None, 30)
    scoretext = gamefont.render("Player Score: " + str(score), 2, [255,0,0])
    boxsize = scoretext.get_rect()
    scoreXpos = (width - boxsize[2])/2

    # running of the game loop
    while True:

        # image display updates
        seconds = clock.tick()/1000.0

        playerImage()

        scoretext = gamefont.render("Player Score: " + str(score), 2, [255,0,0])
        DISPLAYSURF.blit(scoretext, [scoreXpos, 20])

        pygame.display.update()

        # keyboard and/or mouse movements
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()

            elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                    movex = 2
                if event.key == K_LEFT:
                    movex = -2
                if event.key == K_UP:
                    movey = -2
                if event.key == K_DOWN:
                    movey = 2
            elif event.type == KEYUP:
                if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                    movex = 0
                if event.key == K_LEFT:
                    movex = 0
                if event.key == K_UP:
                    movey = 0
                if event.key == K_DOWN:
                    movey = 0

        px = px + movex
        py = py + movey

def playerImage():
    global player
    global px
    global py

    player = pygame.image.load("image 2.png") # load the player image
    DISPLAYSURF.blit(player, (px, py))
    player = pygame.transform.scale(player, (125,125))
    px,py = (width - 125)/2, (height - 125)/2 # pour centrer l'image
    time.sleep(2)

# python's way of running the main routine

if __name__ == "__main__":
    game()
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling implicit

```
pygame.time.sleep
```

that doesn't have the `sleep` method instead of

```
time.sleep
```

Import the `time` module to access its functionality. But watch out to not overwrite the names in your script.
It's generally a bad idea to use `from xxx import *`, just use `import pygame` or `import pygame as xxx`.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer, TidB. I'm still very confused. How do I call the time module correctly? What would you modify in my code? I tried moving my "import time" on an independent line and it did not seem to work. I also tried adding a leading dot (import .time) and it did not work either.

Comment: The thing is: You're importing the `time` module, that's good. But after that, you do `from pygame import *`, which imports pygame's `time` module, overwriting the acces to the original module.

Comment: Okay. Now it works the way is should. Thank you so much TidB!

Answer (score 0):

Since "time" is extremely important in any decent game (Events happening after some time in milliseconds, seconds, minutes, etc), [I've created a way to deal with it natively in my engine](https://github.com/EricsonWillians/Ergame/wiki). (The wiki is far from complete, but you should check out my "EwApp" class, as it provides methods to do exactly that.).

Anyway, the point here is: You should solve this issue without using python's time. Instead, you should work **only** with [pygame.time](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html) (Since using Python's time will PAUSE your entire game for that given amount of time, and that's atrocious). I've developed a simple example adapting my method using "dt", that draws a red rectangle, then draws a green one and waits for 1 second, and then returns to the initial state.

```
import pygame

if __name__ == "__main__":

    pygame.init()
    done = False
    SCREEN_WIDTH = 800
    SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600
    SURFACE_SIZE = 300
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH,SCREEN_HEIGHT))
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    FPS = 1
    time_elapsed = 0

    def check_if_time_has_elapsed_in_seconds(seconds):
        global time_elapsed
        if time_elapsed > seconds*1000:
            time_elapsed = 0
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def get_center(*args):
        if len(args) == 2:
            return ((args[0]/2)-(args[1]/2))

    surf1 = pygame.Surface((SURFACE_SIZE, SURFACE_SIZE))
    pygame.draw.rect(surf1, (0, 255, 0), (0, 0, SURFACE_SIZE, SURFACE_SIZE), 0)
    surf2 = pygame.Surface((SURFACE_SIZE, SURFACE_SIZE))
    pygame.draw.rect(surf2, (255, 0, 0), (0, 0, SURFACE_SIZE, SURFACE_SIZE), 0)

    while not done:

        dt = clock.tick(FPS)
        time_elapsed += dt
        pygame.display.flip()
        screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
        screen.blit(surf1, (get_center(SCREEN_WIDTH, SURFACE_SIZE), get_center(SCREEN_HEIGHT, SURFACE_SIZE)))
        if check_if_time_has_elapsed_in_seconds(1):
            screen.blit(surf2, (get_center(SCREEN_WIDTH, SURFACE_SIZE), get_center(SCREEN_HEIGHT, SURFACE_SIZE)))

        for e in pygame.event.get():
            if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
                done = True

    pygame.quit()
```

With my engine this can be achieved really easily, though. [My engine is open-source and is on github](https://github.com/EricsonWillians/Ergame), but that's the main spirit: Incrementing a "time_elapsed" variable by dt (ticks) within the main loop in order to check wether some amount of time has passed or not. Creating external functions, like I did, make it much easier/handy. This technique is also known as "cooldown". Useful for one hundred thousand things (Like, for example, moving characteres by great amount of pixels, but slowly (After some milliseconds of cooldown)).